# optional bit parameter used in left join

Tags: sql, t-sql

I'd like to return all rows from Table1 and also additional columns from Table2 where the UserId has data in that table.

```
Table1
(
    Table1Id int,
    ItemName varchar(50)
)

Table2
(
    Table2Id int,
    Table1Id int,
    UserId int
)

insert into Table1(Table1Id, ItemName)
values (1, 'Item1'), (2, 'Item2'), (3, 'Item3'), (4, 'Item4')

insert into Table2(Table1Id, UserId)
values (1, 1), (2, 1), (4, 1)

create proc testProc 
    @UserId int = null
    @UserOnlyRows bit = 0
as
begin

    select
        *
    from Table1 t1
        left join Table2 t2 on t2.table2Id = t1.table1Id
        and t2.UserId = @UserId
    where (@UserOnlyRows = 1 and t2.UserId is not null)

end
```

Expected outcome with params @UserId = 1, @UserOnlyRows = 0

```
Table1Id, ItemName, Table2Id, Table1Id, UserId
----------------------------------------------
1         Item1     1         1         1
2         Item2     2         2         1
3         Item3     NULL      NULL      NULL
4         Item4     3         4         1
```

Expected outcome with params @UserId = 1, @UserOnlyRows = 1

```
Table1Id, ItemName, Table2Id, Table1Id, UserId
----------------------------------------------
1         Item1     1         1         1
2         Item2     2         2         1
4         Item3     3         4         1
```

Expected outcome with params @UserId = null, @UserOnlyRows = 0 or 1

```
Table1Id, ItemName, Table2Id, Table1Id, UserId
----------------------------------------------
1         Item1     NULL      NULL      NULL
2         Item2     NULL      NULL      NULL
3         Item3     NULL      NULL      NULL
4         Item4     NULL      NULL      NULL
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to fix the `where` clause:

```
select *
from Table1 t1 left join
     Table2 t2
     on t2.table2Id = t1.table1Id and
        t2.UserId = @UserId
where @UserOnlyRows = 0 or t2.UserId is not null;
```